# Embed iframe on iphone and ipad (safari browser)

Tags: iphone, ipad, iframe, safari, embed

I have issue on ipad/iphone under safari browser for embed iframes.

So, in generally, behavior of this iframes - they keep their height, but iframe contend doesnt shows, so there just blank space instead google embed map or youtube iframe.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I faced this once and I can only solve this by using google API.

Safari doensn't work well with iframe tags.